# FTP сервер из девайса - Android

Tags: java, android-studio, android-sdk, ftp, мобильная-разработка

В ES проводнике есть функция открытия доступа к файлам посредством локальной сети через FTP. Девайс выступает в роли FTP сервера. Собственно вопрос как такое же самое можно написать на Java в Android Studio?

Comment: Что предприняли самостоятельно? Что получилось/не получилось?

Comment: Есть приложение с открытым исходным кодом (swiftp) , оно мне подходит , но ftp сервер создается в локальной сети, а мне нужно чтобы доступ был из любой точки.